# Laravel intervention/image chrome/safari issue

Tags: php, image, safari, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use the intervention/image package in laravel to create profile pictures.

To get used to the plugin a little bit, I used quite a simple code to try out a few things.

Code:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{

$image = Image::make(file_get_contents('http://www.image.com'));

$image->resize(400, 400)->greyscale();

return Response::make($image, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpg'));

});
```

However, Safari does not display the image but downloads it automatically. Tested in Chrome, everything works fine.

Is there really a difference in how browsers handle this? How could I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try `image/jpeg` ?

Comment: Yes man! Thats it! Feel free to post it as an answer. But still, is there a difference how those two formats are handled?

Comment: I mean in general? Does Safari always make a difference here? That would mean that I always have to take care about the two versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how the Safari handles a "malformed" MIME type (to answer one of your comment), but anyway the correct mime type for the JPG is `image/jpeg` (or often `image/pjpeg` in IE, at least versions < 9, IIRC), although you can both find the `.jpg` and `.jpeg` extensions.

```
.jpeg   image/jpeg
.jpeg   image/pjpeg
.jpg    image/jpeg
.jpg    image/pjpeg
```

I took this short sample from a comprehensive list of mime types you can find [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full)

Also, quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG):

> The term "JPEG" is an acronym for the Joint Photographic Experts
>   Group, which created the standard. The MIME media type for JPEG is
>   image/jpeg (defined in RFC 1341), except in Internet Explorer, which
>   provides a MIME type of image/pjpeg when uploading JPEG images